# Extract HTML data outside of a table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have HTML data embedded in an email. Up until now the data has been in tables, however, this time it is not in a table so I'm struggling to capture it all.

Here is how the data appears in the email:

[image]

And here is the HTML code:

```
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head>
<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple>
<div class=WordSection1>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span>
    </p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span>
    </p>
    <div>
        <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span>
        </p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'>-----<o:p></o:p></span>
        </p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Eric Brazer Jr. </span><i><span
                style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></i>
        </p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><i><span
                style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Manager, GB Cod Fixed Gear Sector</span></i><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance</span></b><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>1566 Main Street, Chatham, MA 02633</span><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>(508) 945-2432 x105&nbsp; --&nbsp; Fax: (508) 945-0981</span><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#002776'><a
                href="mailto:melissa@capecodfishermen.org"><span style='color:#002776'>eric@capecodfishermen.org</span></a></span><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#002776'><a
                href="www.capecodfishermen.org"><span
                style='color:#002776'>www.capecodfishermen.org</span></a></span><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas.</span></b><span
                style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    </div>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span>
    </p>
    <div>
        <div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span
                    style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> Stephanie Rafael [mailto:nbsector9@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Thursday, May 23, 2013 2:06 PM<br><b>To:</b> Linda McCann<br><b>Cc:</b> Aaron Dority; Eric Brazer; John Haran; Rob @ NEFS III; XI and XII NEFS INC; Hank Soule; Ben Martens; Jim Reardon; Vito Giacalone; NEFS V; calberto@luzofuel.com; DaveLeveille, NEFS II<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS IX packages available<o:p></o:p></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class=MsoNormal>
        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
    </p>
    <div>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Hello All, <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Below are two package deals that
            are available to lease from NEFS IX. Please let me know if there is any interest. <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Thanks, <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Stephanie <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'><b>Package #1</b> <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBE Cod&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;701 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBW Cod&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13,070 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBE Hadd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;14,100 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBW Hadd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;84,296 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GB YT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;671 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>SNE YT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;153 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GOM YT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2,371 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Plaice&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2,820 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Witch&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1,057 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GB Winter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13,316 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Redfish&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;122 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Hake&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;184 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Pollock&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;7,427 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>SNE Winter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;28,935 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'><b>Asking Price $37,556.65</b> <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'><b>Package #2
            <o:p></o:p>
        </b></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBE Cod&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;432 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBW Cod&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;8,059 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBE Hadd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;14,629 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GBW Hadd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;87,454 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GB YT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1,817 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>SNE YT&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;76 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GOM YT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;200 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Plaice&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2,043 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Witch&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1,413 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>GB Winter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;23,784 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Redfish&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;122 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Hake&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;934 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>Pollock&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;7,899 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>SNE Winter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5,334 <o:p></o:p></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'><b>Asking Price $28,032.91
            <o:p></o:p>
        </b></p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
        </p>
        <div>
            <p class=MsoNormal>
                <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
            </p>
        </div>
        <p class=MsoNormal>-- <br>Stephanie Rafael-DeMello<br>IX Northeast Fishery Sector, Inc.<br>350 South Front
            Street<br>New Bedford, MA 02740<br>508.990.2800<br>Fax:508.990.2899 <o:p></o:p></p>
    </div>
    <div class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'>
</body></html>
```

So trying `BeautifulSoup(html).find_all("table")` fails...

but trying:

```
p_list = []
for i in BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('p'):
    p_list.append(i.next_sibling)
print("p_list:", p_list)
```

produces:

```
p_list: [
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p> </o:p></span></p>,
<div>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'> <o:p></o:p></span>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'>-----<o:p></o:p></span>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Eric Brazer Jr. </span><i><span
            style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></i>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><i><span
            style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Manager, GB Cod Fixed Gear Sector</span></i><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance</span></b><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>1566 Main Street, Chatham, MA 02633</span><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>(508) 945-2432 x105  --  Fax: (508) 945-0981</span><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#002776'><a
            href="mailto:melissa@capecodfishermen.org"><span style="color:#002776">eric@capecodfishermen.org</span></a></span><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#002776'><a
            href="www.capecodfishermen.org"><span style="color:#002776">www.capecodfishermen.org</span></a></span><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>Small Boats.  Big Ideas.</span></b><span
            style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Georgia","serif";color:#1F497D'>-----<o:p></o:p></span>
</p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Eric Brazer Jr. </span><i><span
        style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></i>
</p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Manager, GB Cod Fixed Gear Sector</span></i><span
        style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance</span></b><span
        style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>1566 Main Street, Chatham, MA 02633</span><span
        style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>(508) 945-2432 x105  --  Fax: (508) 945-0981</span><span
        style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#002776'><a
        href="mailto:melissa@capecodfishermen.org"><span
        style="color:#002776">eric@capecodfishermen.org</span></a></span><span
        style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#002776'><a
        href="www.capecodfishermen.org"><span style="color:#002776">www.capecodfishermen.org</span></a></span><span
        style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>Small Boats.  Big Ideas.</span></b><span
        style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p></o:p></span></p>, None,
<div>
    <div style="border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in">
        <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span
                style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> Stephanie Rafael [mailto:nbsector9@gmail.com] <br/><b>Sent:</b> Thursday, May 23, 2013 2:06 PM<br/><b>To:</b> Linda McCann<br/><b>Cc:</b> Aaron Dority; Eric Brazer; John Haran; Rob @ NEFS III; XI and XII NEFS INC; Hank Soule; Ben Martens; Jim Reardon; Vito Giacalone; NEFS V; calberto@luzofuel.com; DaveLeveille, NEFS II<br/><b>Subject:</b> NEFS IX packages available<o:p></o:p></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>, None,
<div>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Hello All,<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Below are two package deals that are
        available to lease from NEFS IX. Please let me know if there is any interest.<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Thanks,<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Stephanie<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Package #1</b><o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Cod               701<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Cod             13,070<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Hadd            14,100<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Hadd          84,296<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB YT                    671<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE YT                  153<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GOM YT               2,371<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Plaice                    2,820<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Witch                    1,057<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB Winter           13,316<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Redfish                 122<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Hake                      184<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Pollock                  7,427<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE Winter         28,935<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Asking Price $37,556.65</b><o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">
        <o:p> </o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Package #2
        <o:p></o:p>
    </b></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Cod               432<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Cod             8,059<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Hadd            14,629<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Hadd          87,454<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB YT                    1,817<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE YT                  76<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GOM YT               200<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Plaice                    2,043<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Witch                    1,413<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB Winter           23,784<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Redfish                 122<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Hake                      934<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Pollock                  7,899<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE Winter         5,334<o:p></o:p></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Asking Price $28,032.91
        <o:p></o:p>
    </b></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">
        <o:p> </o:p>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">
        <o:p> </o:p>
    </p>
    <div>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <o:p> </o:p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p class="MsoNormal">-- <br/>Stephanie Rafael-DeMello<br/>IX Northeast Fishery Sector, Inc.<br/>350 South Front
        Street<br/>New Bedford, MA 02740<br/>508.990.2800<br/>Fax:508.990.2899<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Below are two package deals that are
    available to lease from NEFS IX. Please let me know if there is any interest.<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Thanks,<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Stephanie<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Package #1</b><o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Cod               701<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Cod             13,070<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Hadd            14,100<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Hadd          84,296<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB YT                    671<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE YT                  153<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GOM YT               2,371<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Plaice                    2,820<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Witch                    1,057<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB Winter           13,316<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Redfish                 122<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Hake                      184<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Pollock                  7,427<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE Winter         28,935<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Asking Price $37,556.65</b><o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">
    <o:p> </o:p>
</p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Package #2
    <o:p></o:p>
</b></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Cod               432<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Cod             8,059<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBE Hadd            14,629<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GBW Hadd          87,454<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB YT                    1,817<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE YT                  76<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GOM YT               200<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Plaice                    2,043<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Witch                    1,413<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">GB Winter           23,784<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Redfish                 122<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Hake                      934<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">Pollock                  7,899<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto">SNE Winter         5,334<o:p></o:p></p>,
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"><b>Asking Price $28,032.91
    <o:p></o:p>
</b></p>,None, None]
```

So we can see that the valuable fish data is between the `<p>` tags. But is there a way to extract that data from this large mess of everything found between the `<p>` tags? I figured creating a list and appending the values found between `<p>` tags would work but it doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A well-tabbed prettified HTML would help

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know exactly what you mean. I'm not great with HTML. Are you saying I should've uploaded it in my question differently?

Comment: you have dumped the entire HTML in one line, same with the python output. It is impossible to read that way, someone would have to manually prettify it. It would be better if you add a better version to your question.

Comment: Ok I'll gladly edit it to make it better, but how exactly would you prefer it be presented? Is there a way, when editing or asking a question, to make HTML appear nicer?

Comment: Try printing your parsed document with `BeautifulSoup(html).prettify()`

Comment: Yes…by putting the code in a block, the same way you'd read it in a code editor. Paste in the block, select it, and press Ctrl+K (or click the `{}` button on the toolbar of the editor). While you're making these edits do ***strongly*** consider trimming the code down to something that doesn't approach our 30k character limit. We really want to see a [mcve].

Comment: @udiboy1209 I do believe I've prettified the HTML source code. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @CodyGray So I'm aware that questions should always be clear and concise and I always try to make them so...but this was difficult because HTML questions always seem to require a lot of stuff; the HTML code itself, my code and what I've tried and what I want to accomplish, and that is what I thought I provided. Tell me how wrong I am though because criticism will make me a better question asker.

Comment: When you look at the html, after the first fish everything is the same.  You could have cut the input there. The additional lines add nothing to the disscussion

Comment: Ohh ok I gotcha that's true. Sorry for being so dumb. How did you actually get it to print out so neatly and vertical like that, with the tags neat and everything, while mine was messy and horizontal...?

Comment: Pasted the code into a text editor like sublime and ran format code

Answer (score 0):

This is email HTML hence you don't have properly formatted tables, so you can extract data directly from the `<p>` tags instead.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
lines = [p.get_text() for p in soup.find_all("p")]
```

`get_text()` will strip all HTML tags from the `<p>` tags and leave you with plaintext like this:

```
[u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'-----', u'Eric Brazer Jr. ', u'Manager, GB Cod Fixed Gear Sector', u"Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance", u'1566 Main Street, Chatham, MA 02633', u'(508) 945-2432 x105\xa0 --\xa0 Fax: (508) 945-0981', u'eric@capecodfishermen.org', u'www.capecodfishermen.org', u'Small Boats.\xa0 Big Ideas.', u'\xa0', u'From: Stephanie Rafael [mailto:nbsector9@gmail.com] Sent: Thursday, May 23, 2013 2:06 PMTo: Linda McCannCc: Aaron Dority; Eric Brazer; John Haran; Rob @ NEFS III; XI and XII NEFS INC; Hank Soule; Ben Martens; Jim Reardon; Vito Giacalone; NEFS V; calberto@luzofuel.com; DaveLeveille, NEFS IISubject: NEFS IX packages available', u'\xa0', u'Hello All,', u'Below are two package deals that are available to lease from NEFS IX. Please let me know if there is any interest.', u'Thanks,', u'Stephanie', u'Package #1', u'GBE Cod\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 701', u'GBW Cod\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 13,070', u'GBE Hadd\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 14,100', u'GBW Hadd\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 84,296', u'GB YT\xa0\xa0\xa0 \xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 671', u'SNE YT\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 153', u'GOM YT\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 2,371', u'Plaice\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 2,820', u'Witch\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 1,057', u'GB Winter\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 13,316', u'Redfish\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 122', u'Hake\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 184', u'Pollock\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 7,427', u'SNE Winter\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 28,935', u'Asking Price $37,556.65', u'\xa0', u'Package #2', u'GBE Cod\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 432', u'GBW Cod\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 8,059', u'GBE Hadd\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 14,629', u'GBW Hadd\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 87,454', u'GB YT\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 1,817', u'SNE YT\xa0 \xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 76', u'GOM YT\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 200', u'Plaice\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 2,043', u'Witch\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 1,413', u'GB Winter\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 23,784', u'Redfish\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 122', u'Hake\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 934', u'Pollock\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 7,899', u'SNE Winter\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 5,334', u'Asking Price $28,032.91', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'-- Stephanie Rafael-DeMelloIX Northeast Fishery Sector, Inc.350 South Front StreetNew Bedford, MA 02740508.990.2800Fax:508.990.2899 ']
```

You can now iterate through each string and then look for your table using the index of "Package #1" and "Asking Price" strings using `str.startswith()`, and then split the strings into columns using `str.split()`.

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/M7H6nMyb) I used splits data into list of rows, each row is a tuple.

Comment: Hmm it failed when trying to `print(rows)`  because `rows` is not defined. I'll see what I can figure out on my own.